# How separate Ethernet connection between windows users?

Tags: windows, session, ip, account, separator

I have a windows 10 on a server with 5 RDP clients, when they are connecting to this server I need to separate the internet connection (EX: User1 connect to internet with IP 180.190.180.190, User2 connect to internet with IP 180.190.180.191 and so)

there are some solutions but how I can combine them to get my purpose?
1.if I can assign some local ports for each user (EX: User1 use Port 5000~10000, User2 10001~15000 and so)
2.if I can assign different IP for each User (EX: User 1 use 192.168.1.2 and User2 use 192.168.1.3)
3.if I can find which session made by which user when it make (EX: Session 10,20,30 made by User1 and session 40,50,60 made by User2)

Comment: Why don't you give them their own VM using hyper-v? Then route each connect to the users vm.

Comment: because we use zero client for less sources, if everyone has a VM it needs many sources (RAM and HDD and CPU)

Comment: Sorry but I don't think it is possible, Windows can only use 1 gateway which is setup at device level (osi layer 3). Maybe by using active directory you can setup proxy servers for each individual user, then host a light weight linux proxy server for each internet connection you have.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but there is some problems with proxy, first it use kind of NAT and then WEB Server see all users as an IP address, also it is not possible to use proxy for all ports we need (ICMP, UDP, TCP,)